# RSS Email Campaign for MarketingCloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, rss

I've been using an AMPscript to bring RSS Content into an email for some time now. That work's without issua and I'm ready to try the next step to actually automate a subscription service...

It looks like MailChimp has a feature that does just what I'm looking for, but can't figure out how to do it in MarketingCloud.

Basically the following workflow would be:
1. Maintain a subscription list
2. Check Daily for the most recent post
3. If most recent post is > the date of last send, then
4. Trigger send to subscription list

Sure, I could trigger an email after we publish a blog post, but I'd like to not have to think about it. I'm not authoring the blogs themselves, so it'd take some coordination that wold be better served by automating.

Answer (score 1):

There are a fair few moving parts and a number of variations, so I'm just giving the high-level elements you'll need and you can choose how much you do with AMPScript and how much with SQL.

1. Create a Data Extension (LastArticles)
2. Create a Data Extension with same structure (CurrentArticles)
3. Create a Data Extension, again, with same structure (NewArticles)
4. Create an email that goes and gets articles from the RSS via AMPScript and places all current articles into a Data Extension (CurrentArticles). The target for this email will be an internal inbox or blackhole email address.
5. Create a Query Activity with code similar to this to populate NewArticles with overwrite:

   SELECT *
   FROM
       CurrentArticles ca LEFT JOIN
       LastArticles la
       ON  ca.pubId = la.pubId AND
           la.pubId IS NULL
6. Create an email that places rows from NewArticles into the body as it sends using AMPScript.
7. Create a Query Activity with code similar to this to populate LastArticles with overwrite:

   SELECT *
   FROM
       CurrentArticles
8. Create an Automation that runs 4, 5, then a Verification Activity on NewArticles, 6 and 7.
9. Schedule the Automation to run as frequently as needed.

Comment: May I suggest to exchange number 4 with a Script Activity in Automation Studio? Thats a cleaner way to do that.

Comment: I have a similar question as OP and I'm also wondering about Step 4. How would AMPScript publish the RSS results into a data extension? Or is there a script in Automation Studio that could automatically consume an RSS Feed into a DE like @DonL mentions?

Comment: @David The main thing is you need to run some AMPScript. It could run in an email you send to yourself or it could be called from an SSJS Script Activity in Automation Studio using Platform.Function.ContentBlockByID(). Here's a basic example of AMPScript getting RSS content and saving the results into a Data Extension... https://www.dropbox.com/s/e25oof7yhdtt324/SaveRSS.amp?dl=0&raw=1

Comment: @Macca thank you so much! I didn't understand you can run AMPScript via SSJS, that makes a lot of sense now. Also that sample code is extremely helpful, much appreciated!!